# How Do I run laravel framework from apache 2.4

Tags: server, apache2, php, laravel

I've been trying to get laravel welcome sreen for entire day and nothing..

Here's what I do :

1) Install laravel via composer to the /var/www/html/ like this :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel_v1 4.2 --prefer-dist
```

2) When I run command

```
php artisan serve
```

It says is started on localhost:8000 and when I go there I get welcome screen.

3) Now I create vhost file in /etc/apache2/sites-available called myapp.conf, that has the following content :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 # Host that will serve this project.
    ServerName      app.dev

    # The location of our projects public directory.
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/laravel_v1/public


    # Rewrites for pretty URLs, better not to rely on .htaccess.
    <Directory /var/www/html/laravel_v1/public>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now when I go to app.dev in my browser all I get is apache welcome page. What am I doing wrong in here? Could you please help this young man so he can start with some coding. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.dev
    ServerAlias www.app.dev

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/laravel_v1/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/laravel_v1/public/">
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
         Options -MultiViews
         RewriteEngine On
         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

there is mistake in relative path.